# How does MySQL still function even though I move .ibd file to arbitrary places?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `Person`. AFAIU, the data for this table is stored in `/usr/local/mysql/data/my_database/person.ibd`.

Now, I make an `insert`. Then I check out the contents of `person.ibd` with vim. The data I have just entered is indeed there.

Then, I move the `person.ibd` to my home directory. I again make an `insert` and check out the contents of `person.ibd` with vim. The new data is inserted into the file even though the file is now in my home directory, instead of being at `/usr/local/mysql/data/my_database/person.ibd`.

I repeat this action by moving the `person.ibd` to various other places, such as to `/etc/`. The new data is always inserted.

So, what's going on? How does this happen? Does MySQL search the whole file system before writing the insert to a file in the file system?

### Furthermore:

I open the `person.ibd` with vim and edit a `varchar` type field of a record and save the file. Then I run a `select` but MySQL sees the old data. I exit from MySQL and enter again, but MySQL still sees the old data even though that data does not exist anymore in `person.ibd` and it is replaced by the new content which I have edited into the `person.ibd` file using vim.

So again, what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *NOT* edit a .ibd file!  Things are likely to go wrong:

- The layout of the file is complex, and you are likely to make it unreadable by MySQL.
- The data is probably cached in RAM, so your changes are not immediately recognized and/or they will be overwritten when MySQL decides to rewrite the 16KB block you modified.
- There could be a block split, further rendering your edits a mess.

As for "Moving" a file, let me give you a basic lesson in the *nix filesystem.  A file is (in simplistic terms) two things:  A chunk of data sitting somewhere on disk, and a directory entry pointing to that chunk of data.  When a "file" is "opened" (which MySQL did long ago), it grabs the pointer to the chunk of data, but does not look at the directory entry again.  You did `mv`, which *only* removes one directory entry and creates a new entry.  This new entry points to the *same* chunk of data on disk.

So, until, MySQL *closes* the file, it still has the file, regardless of what path(s) it is known by.

Note that that explains how "hard" links can work trivially.  A second reference (hard link) to the same file is simply a different directory entry pointing to the same chunk of data.

*Please* study the structure of *nix filesystem.  Your incomplete knowledge is rapidly propelling you into disaster!

By the way, if you leave the .ibd in its new location. MySQL won't find it after it restarts.  You will have "lost" that table, and have a repair situation that could be baffling.

Comment: Regarding editing an `.ibd` file: When I edit an `.ibd` file using vim and save my changes, my changes are, for sure, written into the disk right? However since mysql has cached the file, it does not see these changes. Furthermore, the changes I made using vim will in fact be overwritten when mysql decides to write the memory mapped `.ibd` file back to disk, which will completely remove any changes made by my manual edits, and the result will be as if I did not make any edits at all. Am I correct about these?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Caching can be for reading or for writing.  For writing, it is as you say; your change will be overwritten.  For reading, there will be no reason to write the block back to disk, so your change will survive.  Danger.

Comment: One last question: Why doesn't mysql put a lock on `.ibd` files so that no other process will be able to mess with them? Does it make sense to mess with `.ibd` files using anything but mysql?

Comment: I don't know why there is not such a lock.  _Nothing_ else should touch the .ibd _while_ mysqld is running.  While mysqld is stopped, it is just a file; however messing with it could cause mysql to barf when it comes back up.

Answer (score 0):

Did you shut down MySQL and start it again? For shure it won´t work when you try to start it again!
The answer is you are playing with memory buffers, until the database needs to write to disk the error is not present, depending on the buffer size the raise of the error is going to take some time, but the error is warrantee.

Comment: I was interacting via terminal and I wrote `quit` but I guess this only logs out of the account. In other words, I did not restart the server. But still, when I make an insert, how does that data appear in `person.ibd`? Or is `person.ibd` doesn't read from disk, but it reads from memory?

Comment: That´s It you´re using memory as long as you don´t exhaust the buffer. For a test database exhausting a couple of MB will take a long time. Try restarting MySQL.